# 404 error while calling Rest service from Angular

Tags: node.js, httpserver

When I run my server on browser, it showing response not found. I tried on  Firefox, Safari, Chrome, etc. But nothing got improved. It say **response is not defined.**  When I run my http-server, [it fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHwcO.png) to open the page. It will directly jump into the folder path and accessing Html locally, but it is not been served from the server...

This is my code:

```
mod.controller('contacts',contacts);
function contacts(contactsdata){ 
contactsdata.getcontacts()      
.then(function(data){
    this.contacts = data;
})
mod.service("contactsdata",function($http){   
   this.getcontacts = function(){               
        var execute1 = $http.get('http://localhost:3000/contactsinfo')
        var execute2 = execute1.then(function(response){
                return response.data;
            });
                return execute2;
        }
});
```